# Foldable Device UI, Fold and unfold condition

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, responsive-design

is there any way to get user screen state from an foldable device when it's fold condition or unfold condition, i try to did some research and i found this,

```dart
bool isFolded = screenWidth < 600 || screenHeight < 600;
```

but if i use this, and in the future if there any phone with a high quality resolution, it will surely use the unfold condition right?. is there any way to change it. something look like

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: kIsWeb
            ? Text('This is the web version')
            : Text('This is the mobile version'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

it was to detect if we use web/mobile version in flutter, since if i do the foldable device ui and i use the normal ui from fold condition. the design will look to big, to see.

[image]

this was the unfold condition

and this is the fold condition

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can using Microsoft's dual screen library